# Angular 2+ packages comunication

Tags: angular, package

What is the best way to comunicate with the main Angular application from an external package?

*Example*

- I have a main Angular application with a **LoggerService** which deals with log feature.
- In an external package created by myself and installed from package.json I have the **AuthModule** that need the LoggerService to log something.

There is a way to access to **LoggerService** in the main application from the external package?
Maybe it is a wrong approach?

Thanks in advance